# Field myUserDetailsService in com.api.WebSecurityConfig required a single bean, but 2 were found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, components

Full error:
Field myUserDetailsService in com.api.WebSecurityConfig required a single bean, but 2 were found:

- user1: defined in file [/tools/tomcat/instances/webapps/api/WEB-INF/classes/com/api/jwt/users/test1.class]
- user2: defined in file [/tools/tomcat/instances/webapps/api/WEB-INF/classes/com/api/jwt/users/test2.class]

I have the following classes:

**Test1.java**

```
@Service
@Component("user1")
public class Test1 implements UserDetailsService {

    @Value("${test1.username}")
    private String test1Username;

    @Value("${test1.password}")
    private String test1Password;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        if (username != null && username.equals(test1Username)) {
            return new User(username, test1Password, new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found: " + username);
        }
    }

}
```

**Test2.java**

```
@Service
@Component("user2")
public class Test2 implements UserDetailsService {

    @Value("${test2.username}")
    private String test2Username;

    @Value("${test2.password}")
    private String test2Password;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        if (username != null && username.equals(test2Username)) {
            return new User(username, test2Password, new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found: " + username);
        }
    }

}
```

**SpringMainApplication.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**/access-token").permitAll().
            anyRequest().authenticated().and().
            exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

**JwtRequestFilter.java**

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "user1")
    private Test1 test1;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "user2")
    private Test2 test2;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal() throws ServletException, IOException {
        // SOME CODE
    }
```

I thought that by using `@Component` and `@Qualifier`, I would be able to set up two user detail classes, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there anything that I am missing or is it just not possible in this design?

If I make another class named `MyUserDetailsService.java` then compiling works and the correct classes are being accessed in the respective endpoints. I just don't understand why `MyUserDetailsService` must exist and I cannot use the `Test1` and `Test2` as user classes.

**EDIT:**

**Test1.java**

```
@Service
@Component("myUserDetailsService")
public class Test1 implements UserDetailsService {

    @Value("${test1.username}")
    private String test1Username;

    @Value("${test1.password}")
    private String test1Password;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        if (username != null && username.equals(test1Username)) {
            return new User(username, test1Password, new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found: " + username);
        }
    }

}
```

**Test2.java**

```
@Service
@Component("myUserDetailsService")
public class Test2 implements UserDetailsService {

    @Value("${test2.username}")
    private String test2Username;

    @Value("${test2.password}")
    private String test2Password;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        if (username != null && username.equals(test2Username)) {
            return new User(username, test2Password, new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found: " + username);
        }
    }

}
```

**SpringMainApplication.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "myUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**/access-token").permitAll().
            anyRequest().authenticated().and().
            exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

**JwtRequestFilter.java**

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private Test1 test1;

    @Autowired
    private Test2 test2;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal() throws ServletException, IOException {
        // SOME CODE
    }
```

This gives me the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.api.SpringMainApplication];

nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException:

Annotation-specified bean name 'myUserDetailsService' for bean class [com.api.jwt.users.Test2DetailsService] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.api.jwt.users.Test1DetailsService]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need qualifiers for these declarations. Spring can inject those by type as  there's a single matching bean for each type (Test1 and Test2).

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "user1")
private Test1 test1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "user2")
private Test2 test2;
```

However you do need need a qualifier for this declaration because you have two implementations of `UserDetailsService` and spring doesn't know which one to inject, resulting in your error.

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
```

**Edit**

In your updated example you are defining two beans with the same bean id

```
@Component("myUserDetailsService")
public class Test1 implements UserDetailsService {

@Component("myUserDetailsService")
public class Test2 implements UserDetailsService {
```

This causes the new error you're seeing (It might help to review [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html)):

> Annotation-specified bean name 'myUserDetailsService' for bean class
> [com.api.jwt.users.Test2DetailsService] conflicts with existing,
> non-compatible bean definition of same name and class
> [com.api.jwt.users.Test1DetailsService]

In your example it doesn't really make sense to have two `UserDetailsService` implementations. You could refactor by combining them into a single class.

Comment: I edited my question. Do you mind taking another look please?

Comment: I think the issue I am having is that I cannot load user1 and user2 at the same time. It is either one or the other, but I need them both to be loaded because they have their own specific token secrets and endpoints.

Comment: Basically my question is whether there is a way to use `Test1` and `Test2` without having a `MyUserDetailsService` class. Right now I have all 3 classes and it works, but it would be ideal if I can remove `MyUserDetailsService` so I won't have double code.